# How to make apollo server prehandler

Tags: apollo, apollo-server

Is there a way to add prehandler for apollo server so that from prehandler i can throw error that apollo will catch and send as response in apollo format? Or maybe there is a helper to format error for response?

How i do it like this with custom getGqlErr helper that will get existing error or generate it:

```
onst apolloHandler = apolloServer.createHandler({ path: '/api/graphql' })

const apiHandler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse): Promise<void> => {
  try {
    await prehandler({ req, res } as Ctx)
  } catch (e) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    res.end(
      JSON.stringify({
        errors: [
          {
            message: 'Prehandler Error',
            extensions: {
              langsMsg: getGqlErr(e),
              code: 'prehandler custom error',
            },
          },
        ],
      })
    )
    return
  }

  apolloHandler(req, res)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done in context function.

```
const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
  schema,
  formatError: (err): any => {
    console.log(err)
    return err
  },
  async context(ctx: Ctx): Promise<Ctx> {
    await prehandler(ctx)

    return ctx
  },
})
```